# django : form_valid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'form'

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm wondering how I can solve this issue in my `form_valid()` function :

> form_valid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'form'

I'm using `Django Class Based View` and `formsets`. But, it could be possible to get `IntegrityError` and I added a `try/except` in order to save the formset when forms are valid, and redirect the template with an error message when I get this issue.

```
class AnimalCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Animal
    template_name = 'animal_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AnimalCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        foo_queryset = Foo.objects.all()
        context['FooFormSets'] = FooFormSet(self.request.POST or None, self.request.FILES or None,
                                                      prefix='foo', queryset=foo_queryset)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, request, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formsets = context['FooFormSets']
        if form.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            try:
                if formsets.is_valid():
                    formsets.instance = self.object
                    formsets.save(commit=False)
                    for element in formsets:
                        element.save(commit=False)
                        formsets.save()
            except IntegrityError:
                messages.error(self.request, _(f"Issue with foo"))
                return render(request, self.template_name)

        return super(AnimalCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

I would like to know what I have to do in my `form_valid()` function in order to solve my issue and redirect user on the same template form with error message.

Thank you

Comment: `def form_valid(self, request, form):` should be `def form_valid(self, form):`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`def form_valid(self, request, form):` should be `def form_valid(self, form):`.

You can access request object through `self.request`.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    formsets = context['FooFormSets']
    if form.is_valid():
        self.object = form.save()
        try:
            if formsets.is_valid():
                formsets.instance = self.object
                formsets.save(commit=False)
                for element in formsets:
                    element.save(commit=False)
                    formsets.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            messages.error(self.request, _(f"Issue with foo"))
            return render(self.request, self.template_name)
```

Additionally, you don't need to call `if form.is_valid():` a second time as that's already been determined - hence executing `form_valid`.

Comment: Yes you're right ! I just have one more question, Do I have to replace `except IntegrityError` or it's good ? Because `formsets.save() ` is the direct cause to the folowwing exception.

Comment: If you expect an `IntegrityError` then it doesn't hurt but without more info on your models I have no idea. For example a duplicate key could cause an error if your foreign key is a `OneToOneField`

Comment: I will create a new question according to my `IntegrityError` thank you !